# How to find tomorrow and yesterday date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to filter a form to show the dates for tomorrow and yesterday.

The form is working well for today with the following macro

```
if [Forms]![issues]![OpenedDateFilter]="today"
applyfilter
where condition
(Year([Opened Date])=Year(Date()) And Month([Due Date])=Month(Date()) And 
Day([Opened Date])=Day(Date()))
```

Thank you for any help or pointers.

Comment: If today is `Date()` then yesterday is `Date() - 1` and tomorrow is `Date() + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account that "tommorrow" and "yesterday" may fall in another year. Thus, use *DateAdd*:

```
Dim Offset As Integer

Select Case [Forms]![issues]![OpenedDateFilter]
    Case "tomorrow"
        Offset = 1
    Case "yesterday"
        Offset = -1
    Case Else
        Offset = 0
End Select

Me.Filter = "[Opened Date] = #" & Format(DateAdd("d", Offset, Date), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

If `[Due Date]` is not a typo, you can use *DateSerial*:

```
Me.Filter = "[Opened Date] = #" & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month([Due Date]), Day(Date) + Offset), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: The month being used in the comparison is based on `[Due Date]`, not `[Opened Date]`.  And `DateAdd("d", Offset, Date)` can be simplified to `Date() + Offset`.

Comment: Thanks, missed that. Answer is expanded.